# sending arduino data to python and delimiter

Tags: python, arduino

I have an arduino that is reading data and sending it to my computer which is then read by a python script, to be saved as a csv file.

however at the end of the line there is a "\r\n" that pops up.  I essentially want all these values to be stored as a float, not a string.

here is my py script

```
import serial
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


index = 0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
vol = 1.0
tempHL = []
tempWL = []
tempCL = []
timeL = []
humidL = []
dataT = timeL, tempWL, tempCL, tempHL, humidL



while True:
    index +=1
    #temp = float(ser.readline())
    temp = ser.readline()
    time, tempW, tempC, tempH, humidity = temp.split(",")
    print "Time: ", time, " TempW: ", tempW, " TempC: ", tempC, " TempH: ", tempH, " Humidity: ", humidity
    print


    timeL.append(time)
    tempWL.append(tempW)
    tempCL.append(tempC)
    tempHL.append(tempH)
    humidL.append(humidity)

        with open("/home/matthew/sketchbook/VaporPod/VaporPod/data.csv", 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for t, tW, tC, tH, h in zip(dataT[0], dataT[1], dataT[2], dataT[3], dataT[4]):
            writer.writerow([t, tW, tC, tH, h])
            #print "Time: ", t, " TempWater: ", tW, " TempCube: ", tC, " tempHumidity: ", tH, " Humidity: ", h
    #print


    f.close()
```

Here is my Arduino code.

```
void loop() {  


  monitor.setCursor(0, 1);
  sensors.requestTemperatures();


  //---from humidity sensor

  float tempWater = sensors.getTempF(waterTemp);
  float tempCube = sensors.getTempF(cubeTemp);

  float humd = myHumidity.readHumidity();
  float tempH = (myHumidity.readTemperature()) * 1.8 + 32.0;


  //time

  Serial.print(millis() / 1000);
  Serial.print(",");



  //Water TempC
  Serial.print(tempWater);
  //printTemperature(waterTemp);
  Serial.print(",");


  //---cube temp

  Serial.print(tempCube);
  //printTemperature(cubeTemp);
  Serial.print(",");



  //---tempC from humidity sensor
  Serial.print(tempH, 1);
  Serial.print(",");

  //humidity
  Serial.print(humd, 1);
  Serial.print("\n");

  delay(1000);


}
```

Here is a screenshot of the saved csv file

[image: a screen shot of the data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time, tempW, tempC, tempH, humidity = map(float,temp.split(","))
```

maybe?